# On integers $n\geq 1$ for which $n$ divides $\sum_{k=1}^n R_k$, where $R_k$ denotes the $k$-th Ramanujan prime

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, divisibility, analytic-number-theory, prime-gaps

For integers $n\geq 1$ in this post we denote the Ramanujan primes as $R_n$, see for example the Wikipedia [*Ramanujan prime*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_prime) or [1]. I don't know if my question is in the literature but I think that it should be very difficult to solve. Compare with the sequence and related literature added for the sequence *A045345* from The Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

> **Question (Edited).** I would like to know if there exist infinitely many integers $n\geq 1$ such that $$n\mid\sum_{k=1}^n R_k.$$
>   Alternatively, if the question is difficult to answer, can you provide heuristic reasonings tell me about whether there are infinitely many or well a finite number of terms for this integer sequence? You can to invoke conjectures from the literature in your discussion. **Many thanks.**

Since I think that it is very difficult I'm asking if one can do some work about the question or add some reasoning or heuristic.

The sequence of integers $n\geq 1$ for which $\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n R_k}{n}$ is integer starts as $$1,3,5,63,3669,8933,\ldots$$
For example (the sequence in OEIS for Ramanujan primes is *A104272*) $$\frac{1}{5}\left(2+11+17+29+41\right)=\frac{100}{5}\in\mathbb{Z}.$$

### References:

[1] Jonathan Sondow, John W. Nicholson and Tony D. Noe, *Ramanujan Primes: Bounds, Runs, Twins, and Gaps*, Journal of Integer Sequences, Vol. 14 (2011), Article 11.6.2.

Comment: There isn't even many properties known about Ramanujan numbers in general, right? This would be a difficult problem to solve or even make progress, I believe.

Comment: Many thanks for your attention @GarethMa I'm agree with you, if there are no feedback in next days I can delete it.

Comment: My python program is still trying to generate more ramanujan primes, since the oeis sequence only gives the first 10k (And you've listed the $n$ under that)... :P

Comment: Many thanks again, the only terms of our sequence that I know, are those that were showed in the body of the post. I didn't know more terms @GarethMa I checked it with a Pari/GP in my computer up to $10^4$.

Comment: How did you find them then?

Comment: Not answering the actual question about infinite/finite, but Perl's ntheory module (in C) will generate Ramanujan primes quite quickly (up to 10^9 in 5 seconds), also in segments, and fast nth and counts (e.g. the 10^11th ramanujan prime in under 1 second).  A quick look says 3, 5, 63, 3669, 8933, 19045, 2979931, 9661009, 204623155, 318052951, 459663333.

Comment: Many thanks for your contribution, and sequence @DanaJ